# Can R find out how many times a key phrases appear in a corpus or document?

Tags: r, n-gram

I did it for a single word but I cant seem to figure out how to get it work for bigram? Let's say I want to find how many times the key phrase "opening hours" appear in the text document how can I do it? Is there any library?

Comment: You can check `unnest_tokens` from `tidytext` specify the `token` and `n`. then get the count

Comment: have you heard of tidy text?

Comment: no i never heard of tidytext. im using tm package with snowballc are they the same?